# Windows kernel mode WFP filtering: tried to add filters failling

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, win32-process, wfp

I am tried to add Windows kernel mode WFP filters, tried to add filters.
I have near about WFP 590 filters to add but I do not see all of the filters getting added.
checked Windows eventvwr, saw error event with following message

"The filtering engine has exceeded the configured threshold to process a transaction"

```
eventId 1030 source WFP
Transaction Watchdog Timeout
The filtering engine has exceeded the configured threshold to process a transaction. This could indicate a suboptimal policy configuration that may cause temporary network outages.
    Owning Process ID: 1968
    Transaction Time (msec): 969
    Transaction Commit Time (msec): 953
    Configured Threshold (msec): 500
```

Is there any upper limit/threshold on filters can added in WFP ?

Comment: That's a lot of filters. Might be worth implementing them in a callout instead. Or you could call FwpmEngineSetOption() with the FWPM_ENGINE_TXN_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_IN_MSEC option.

Comment: @Luke thanks, would crossing threshold cause failure filter additions?
Did not find any MSDN doc that how many max filters can be added
found a link https://scorpiosoftware.net/2022/12/25/introduction-to-the-windows-filtering-platform/

Comment: I don't see any documentation about how it behaves.